# Dataset for tensorflow shuffle() messing up predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi I created a little function to prepare my dataset before training as below which reshuffles also. But this functionality runs every time I get the output without running the function again.

```
def create_ds(x, y, shuffle=True, batch_size=512):
    # Renaming columns in the input df
    x = MyPackage.rename_df(x)

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x), y))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(len(x))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds
```

Then I use this to create a tensorflow dataset for train and test.

```
train_ds = create_ds(
        train_df,
        train_df['target'].values,
        shuffle=True,
        batch_size=batch_size,
    )

test_ds = create_ds(
        test_df,
        test_df['target'].values,
        shuffle=False,
        batch_size=batch_size_test,
    )


--- Here I compile the model not included -- 

model.fit(
        train_ds,
        epochs=epochs,
        callbacks=[
            tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join(output_path, "logs")),
            tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_auc", patience=10),
        ],
        validation_data=test_ds,
        verbose=2,
    )

# predict
pred_1 = model.predict(train_ds) 
pred_2 = model.predict(train_ds)
```

But the pred_1 != pred_2. This is because of the `shuffle = True` when building the `train_ds` - it gets swapped around still. I thought once I had shuffled the data; why is it doing it every time I call it.

For example - I predicted on 3 rows and got for pred_1:

```
array([[0.51523584],
       [0.50634336],
       [0.51264596]], dtype=float32)
```

and pred_2:

```
array([[0.50634336],
       [0.51523584],
       [0.51264596]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Dataset shuffle has a parameter called "reshuffle_each_iteration" wich defaults to True. Set that to False

Comment: That worked! But so is that shuffling once and then that's it? :)

Comment: Yes, here you can see the example: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle